# delay opening link while showing an alert jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I want to delay opening the url until the user has closed the alert which pops up on click. Presently the alert shows for a fraction of a second then goes to the url and it's not really long enough for them to even read the alert so I want them to be able to close it on their own time by clicking on or outside it. I've tried `preventDefault` on the event but this stops the alert from showing at all and still opens the url. The code is:

```
var callMe = function (e) {
    swal("Thanks!", "We will be in touch!", "success");
}
$("li").on("click", function (e) {
    callMe();
});
```

I am using [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) for the alert which seems to work OK with jQuery but it's just not showing long enough.

Answer (score 1):

`swal` appears to return a promise you can use to check the confirmation state when it's confirmed/closed.

[reference](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)

```
swal("Thanks!", "We will be in touch!", "success")
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(`Clicked button, value: ${value}`);
  })
```